run npm scripts in chain even if previous ones failed
When I used ; then it is giving error-
Error: No tests found.
Make sure that arguments are regular expressions matching test files.
You may need to escape symbols like "$" or "*" and quote the arguments.
I have below scripts in package.json
"testChrome": "npx playwright test --project=chrome ; npm run generateReport",
"generateReport":"allure generate output/allure-results -o output/allure-report --clean --single-file"
I run tests by- npm run testChrome.
Issue is if there are any test failures then the 'npm run generateReport' getting skipped and it did not run script to generate report.
I used && instead of ; but it will only execute 'npm run generateReport' if previous script is fully success.
When I used ; then it is giving error-
Error: No tests found.
Make sure that arguments are regular expressions matching test files.
You may need to escape symbols like "$" or "*" and quote the arguments.
Note: I had used this before in codeceptjs, but in current project I am using playwright directly without having codeceptjs.
I want npm run generateReport to be executed regardless or passing/failing of previous script

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can pipe the exit code to true to ensure the follow up command is ran.
npx playwright test --project=chrome || true && npm run generateReport


Thanks, but no luck. I tried with || true &&, and now  'npm run generateReport' didn't executed even the previous script is success.
it only works with- 'npx playwright test --project=chrome && npm run generateReport'----- only when the previous tests are all passed.

FYI I am running tests in windows, above scripts are written in the package.json file. I use VScode powershell terminal to execute 'npm run testChrome'.
I use the same with ; symbol in my other project which based on Codecept+playwright. Not sure why it is not working with playwright only project
